# How to load and save models in Sparkling Water

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I want to store a created model within sparkling water as a binary file so that I can can reload it with a different application.

What is the best way?

Comment: There is a solution available at https://support.h2o.ai/support/solutions/articles/17000012117-getting-started-with-sparkling-water0 

However, on https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/issues/207 a different way is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [support article](https://support.h2o.ai/support/solutions/articles/17000012117-getting-started-with-sparkling-water0) is outdated and was just demonstrating something we already incorporated into our API. That sample code is using an outdated `water.serial.ObjectTreeBinarySerializer`, which doesn't exist anymore.

The most convenient way is to use the [ModelSerializationSupport](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/water/support/ModelSerializationSupport.scala).